# Pass, how to cache passphrase

Tags: password, gpg, gpg-agent

I'm started to use unix password manager [Pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/)

Some passwords are not critical to me and I'm using them very often

So it's became very annoying to me to type passphrase to get some password.

Is there a way to type passphrase only once?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What operating system are you using? Who asks for the password? Is it `sudo`? Is it `pass` itself?

Comment: The underlying encryption software used by `pass` is `gpg`.  So your question is really a `gpg` question, how do you cache your password.

Comment: What is the scenario for this 'Is there a way to type password only once?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hymie** is right, the question is related to gpg.

The solution is tricky for me, so here's one for OSX:

1. Install **pinentry-mac**

   brew install pinentry-mac
2. Create file ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf with lines:

   pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac

   default-cache-ttl 86400

   max-cache-ttl 86400
3. When pinentry program requires a passphrase, check box to keep this passphrase

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended functionality: you *want* to be prompted for a passphrase when you access encrypted material.

You can, however, as a trade off between security and convenience, cache your passphrase in an agent running as a daemon. This enables you to be prompted for the passphrase once, authenticate, and then for the credential to be held in memory for a specified and configurable amount of time so that subsequent requests within that time frame are handed to the agent.

There are a number of applications that handle this: [gpg-agent](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) ships with GPG. Or you could use [keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) or [Envoy](https://github.com/vodik/envoy), both of which manage SSH and GPG keys.

You can start these agents when you login, the [Arch Wiki has the details](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent).