# How to make the default-cache-ttl option of gpg-agent work?

Tags: gpg, cache, gpg-agent, password-store, pinentry

I use pass as a password manager. I would
like my passphrase to be cached during a certain amount of time to avoid
retyping my passphrase every time that I want to clip one of my passwords. 
Pass is using [gpg-agent](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/) to decrypt
passwords.

According to the [man page](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#option%20--options) and a [previously answered question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247928/pass-how-to-cache-passphrase), the solution is to set up the following options in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
default-cache-ttl 3600
max-cache-ttl 86400
```

Unfortunately, it does not work on my machine, I am asked for my passphrase each time I ask for a password.

I have verified that my `gpg-agent.conf` is read by adding and removing the
`no-grab` option. This works fine.

I am on a Debian machine with i3wm desktop. So I do not use gnome-keyring manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading gnupg from 1.4 to 2.1 which seemed to simplify a lot the configuration.

However, it generated an error of migration of the secret key between gpg and
gpg2.

gpg2 generated the following error message when I was requiring password from
pass:

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

The solution came from this [previous issue](https://github.com/IJHack/qtpass/issues/92#issuecomment-255377497):

```
gpg --export [ID] > public.key
gpg --export-secret-keys [ID] > private.key
gpg2 --import public.key
gpg2 --import private.key
rm public.key private.key
```

with [ID] being the id of my key. It imports correctly the keys from gpg to gpg2.

Finally I rebooted and now my passphrase is cached, which makes me a really happy user of pass.